Apply Style variation to specific pages
I notice wordpress themes come with the ability to have "style variations". Can one apply a style variation to a specific "page/ post" as oppose to a block or section or global site?
Or maybe apply a variation to one page/post template and another to another page/post template?

According to the documentation on Style Variations, it would not appear so. The intent of Style Variations is to be "skins" for your theme and site, rather than for individual pages.
However, CSS can be used to apply different styles to specific pages: the <body> tag of each page has classes that can be used to identify pages, and custom classes can be added using the body_class filter.
add_filter( 'body_class', static function ( $classes ) {
    if ( ! sewd427356_style_variation_logic() ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $classes[] = 'sewd427356-style-variation';

    return $classes;
} );

body.sewd427356-style-variation p {
    color: #f00;
}


Figured as much. I was hoping that I could have utilized the style variations as opposed to creating multiple styles( and stylesheets) to facilitate this and would have been a matter of switching the style based on the page. I don't suppose these variations could be identified by css variables or using style names. Thus e.g. $classes = ['emarald']
